# Pass nested C++ vector as built-in style multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, nested

If I have a vector in C++, I know I can safely pass it as an array (pointer to the contained type):

```
void some_function(size_t size, int array[])
{
    // impl here...
}

// ...
std::vector<int> test;
some_function(test.size(), &test[0]);
```

Is it safe to do this with a nested vector?

```
void some_function(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, int* multi_dimensional_array)
{
    // impl here...
}

// ...

std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > test;
// initialize with non-jagged dimensions, ensure they're not empty, then...
some_function(test.size(), test[0].size(), test[0][0].size(), &test[0][0][0]);
```

Edit:

If it is not safe, what are some alternatives, both if I can change the signature of `some_function`, and if I can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to use `&top_level_vector[0]` and pass that to a C-style function that expects an `int*` isn't safe.

To support correct C-style access to a multi-dimensional array, all the bytes of all the hierarchy of arrays would have to be contiguous.  In a c++ `std::vector`, this is true for the items *contained* by a vector, but not for the vector itself.  If you try to take the address of the top-level vector, ala `&top_level_vector[0]`, you're going to get an array of vectors, not an array of `int`.

The vector structure isn't simply an array of the contained type.  It is implemented as a structure containing a pointer, as well as size and capacity book-keeping data.  Therefore the question's `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >` is more or less a hierarchical tree of structures, stitched together with pointers.  Only the final leaf nodes in that tree are blocks of contiguous `int` values.  And each of those blocks of memory are not necessarily contiguous to any other block.

In order to interface with C, you can only pass the contents of a single `vector`.  So you'll have to create a single `std::vector<int>` of size `x * y * z`.  Or you could decide to re-structure your C code to handle a single 1-dimensional stripe of data at a time.  Then you could keep the hierarchy, and only pass in the contents of leaf vectors.

Comment: I added my own answer because it seemed like none of the other answers put it all together, or were updated to add the contents of comments.  I got an understanding from all the answers and comments, though, so I am also upvoting the most useful ones.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to do this with a nested vector?

Yes, IF you want to access the *inner-most* vector only, and as long you know the number of elements it contains, and you don't try accessing more than that.

But seeing your function signature, it seems that you want to acess all three dimensions, in that case, no, that isn't valid.

The alternative is that you can call the function `some_function(size_t size, int array[])` for each *inner-most* vector (if that solves your problem); and for that you can do this trick (or something similar):

```
void some_function(std::vector<int> & v1int)
{
    //the final call to some_function(size_t size, int array[]) 
    //which actually process the inner-most vectors
    some_function(v1int.size(), &v1int[0]);
}
void some_function(std::vector<std::vector<int> > & v2int)
{
    //call some_function(std::vector<int> & v1int) for each element!
    std::for_each(v2int.begin(), v2int.end(), some_function);
}

//call some_function(std::vector<std::vector<int> > & v2int) for each element!
std::for_each(test.begin(), test.end(), some_function);
```

Comment: What if I want to call the function `void some_function(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, int* multi_dimensional_array)`?

Comment: @Merlyn: I already said that that isn't possible, if you want to access all the three dimensions in the function, because all the inner-most vectors aren't guaranteed to use contiguous memory; in fact, its very unlikely.

Comment: Right.  I am also looking for the simplest alternative.  I think it's going to be `std::vector<int> array(x * y * z)`, but I'd like to see if anyone has a better idea, or at least a good write-up of that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "no".

Elements here `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > > test;` are not replaced in contiguous memory area.

Answer (score 1):

You can only expect `multi_dimensional_array` to point to a contiguos memory block of size  `test[0][0].size() * sizeof(int)`. But that is probably not what you want.

Comment: So in memory I am only guaranteed to have a X*Y count of contiguous arrays size/count Z (Z being the inner-most dimension), but those blocks aren't guaranteed to be contiguous to each other?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: the constructor and the `push_back` function of the std::vector<T> class will typically call `new T[]` internally. When `T`is itself a vector type, this will result in a constructor call at least once for each array element, resulting in a sequence of calls to `new T[]` for each of the innermost vectors. And if you call `new T[]` twice it is very unlikely (for most memory managers: totally impossible) to get two contiguos blocks of memory.

Answer (score 1):

It is erroneous to take the address of any location in a vector and pass it. It might seem to work, but don't count on it.

The reason why is closely tied to why a vector is a vector, and not an array. We want a vector to grow dynamically, unlike an array. We want insertions into a vector be a constant cost and not depend on the size of the vector, like an array until you hit the allocated size of the array.

So how does the magic work? When there is no more internal space to add a next element to the vector, a new space is allocated twice the size of the old. The old space is copied to the new and the old space is no longer needed, or valid, which makes dangling any pointer to the old space. Twice the space is allocated so the average cost of insertion to the vector that is constant.

Comment: I believe this is mandated by the standard to work, because of what you said?  That is, assuming you don't change the vector inside the call to `some_function`.  This info applies to the top call.  If this is not true, let me know, though I think I found answers that confirm the top code works on SO while searching for dupes of this question.  It is really the 2nd part of my sample code that I suspect might not work, and isn't completely covered by your answer here.

Comment: Oh, I think I might see your point now.  If one of the inner-most arrays gets resized, then the top-most memory configuration will no longer be contiguous (if it ever was).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to simply copy the contents of the nested vector into one vector and pass it to that function. But this depends on how much overhead you are willing to take.

That being sad: Nested vectorS aren't good practice. A matrix class storing everything in contiguous memory and managing access is really more efficient and less ugly and would possibly allow something like `T* matrix::get_raw()` but the ordering of the contents would still be an implementation detail.

Comment: Are there existing implementations of such a matrix that you know of?

Comment: @Merlyn Unfortunately there is non in the standard and Boost.ublas is probably overkill. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/ymatrix.aspx Looks nice and fairly complete. I haven't used it though.

Comment: This also looks good.  Have you used it?  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: @Merlyn: There actually is one in the Standard, called `valarray`. However, it's a pain to use. Personally, I just calculate the index, `[ grid_size * z + row_size * y + x ]`, since it's really not that much work. `multi_array` is often recommended.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Wow, I completely forgot about `valarray`. Probably for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - no, it is not. Did you try compiling this? And why not just pass the whole 3D vector as a reference? If you are trying to access old C code in this manner, then you cannot.

Comment: Yes I compiled it, and no I didn't expect it to work (it seemed to be buggy when I tried it).  I asked the question in case it somehow did work and I was just doing things wrong, or if there are easy alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much safer to pass the vector, or a reference to it:

```
void some_function(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> & vector);
```

You can then get the size and items within the function, leaving less risk for mistakes. You can copy the vector or pass a pointer/reference, depending on expected size and use.

If you need to pass across modules, then it becomes slightly more complicated.

Comment: `If you need to pass across modules, then it becomes slightly more complicated`.  What would be involved?  Ideally I'd be able to use this to call existing c-style code.

Comment: If the modules used different versions of the standard library, you may run into issues. I'm not sure all the details, never had the problem myself, but I have heard of it. On the other hand, you gain the fact you're only passing one parameter and there's less chance for mistakes. Depending on what you're doing, this may or may not work for you.