# Dynamically creating 2d arrays

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

This is a situation where I have a function that receives the number of rows and columns of a ray and I want to dynamically create it within the function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int **array;
array = malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
if(array == NULL)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit or return
    }
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
    array[i] = malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int));
    if(array[i] == NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit or return
        }
    }
```

this does not work because in VS 2011, it says that 
array = malloc(n * sizeof (int *));
void * cannot be assigned to int *
How do I fix that?

Comment: If your question were about how to create 2d arrays dynamically in C++, it would be a dupe of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773108/initializing-series-of-arrays-with-for-loops-at-c/5773287#5773287 . However, this isn't what your question is about (it is about how to fix the compiler error/assign the result of malloc to an `int*`).  But you may want to read that question anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual C++ is a C++ compiler, and C++ requires you to cast `void*`s explicitly, unlike C which allows implicit casting of `void*`s.

Try

```
array = (int**)malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
```

However, that's how you would do it in C, and if you decide later to change the data from `int`s to some sort of object, the object's constructor wouldn't be called, because you used `malloc`. If you want to do it the more C++-ish way, which works for all data types, you would use `new`:

```
int** array = new int*[nrows];

for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
    array[i] = new int[ncolumns];
```

This way also saves you from having to calculate the object's size with `n * sizeof(type)`.

**However**, if you choose to use `malloc` to allocate a block of memory, you **must** use `free` to deallocate it; conversely, if you choose to use `new` to allocate a block of memory, you need to use `delete` to delete it (*Remember to use `delete[]` on arrays and plain `delete` on non-arrays*). Using `delete` on a `malloc`'d memory block or `free` on a `new`'d memory block results in undefined behaviour. The reason for this is that `malloc` allocates memory on the *heap* but `new` allocates memory on the *free-store*. They could happen to be the same thing; in fact, some implementations of `new` and `delete` use `malloc` and `free` under the hood, but that's compiler-dependent, so don't **ever** do it.

Note that you can use `malloc` and `free` in the same program, but that is not recommended because you could easily forget which one allocated a specific block of memory and use the wrong deallocation function on it.

Comment: ... or a std::vector - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773108/initializing-series-of-arrays-with-for-loops-at-c/5773287#5773287

Comment: Gotta teach students long division before letting them use a calculator :)

Comment: @Seth: +1 for that :)  You may want to mention coupling malloc/new with free/delete.

Comment: @Seth: By that logic, you gotta teach students writing compilers before letting them program in any compiled language...

Comment: @Fred That would be fine with me.

Comment: @Seth: And in what language would that compiler be allowed to be written? :-)

Comment: @FredOverflow, Seth: Many students have been taught machine/assembly before graduating to higher level languages.  They might not have built the calculator, but they at least learned what it did for them.

Comment: @Merlyn I didn't mean actually literally building a calculator, I meant you need to know how to do things manually and how stuff works before having something do it for you. Learning machine/assembly is a good place to start in my opinion.

Comment: @Seth: Oh, oops.  I meant I was agreeing with you :)  I was just trying to extend the metaphor of building a compiler to building a calculator.

Comment: @Merlyn oh, I looked up just now and you were the one who +1'd my first comment. I should have known :)